# How can I run a cron command with environmental variables set by kubernetes secret

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, cron, debian, kubernetes

I'm using kubernetes secret as my environment variable
(http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/secrets/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables).

I've check whether env vars set correctly by

```
kubectl exec -it my_pod bash
```

1.

```
echo $RAILS_ENV #=> staging
```

2.

```
bin/rails c;
puts ENV['RAILS_ENV'] #=> staging
```

It works fine for my rails application and bash command, but doesn't work when executing cron process.

I've read some post to understand cron process (e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables) and know that I should source .profile or .bashrc before executing cron command like.

```
$ crontab -l

* * * * * . $HOME/.profile; /bin/bash -l -c 'echo rails_env=$RAILS_ENV >> /tmp/cron_test.log'

* * * * * . $HOME/.bashrc; /bin/bash -l -c 'echo rails_env=$RAILS_ENV >> /tmp/cron_test.log'
```

but both doesn't work for me ˊˋ

result

```
rails_env=
```

Any help will be appreciated!

===

**[update: add kubernetes yaml config]**

Both environment variables assign by kubernetes config and kubernetes secret can read in bash and rails application, but doesn't work in cron process.

deployment.yaml

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my_rails
  ...
    command:
    - bash
    args:
    - /tmp/run_cron.sh
  ...
    env:
      - name: RAILS_ENV
        value: staging
      - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: rails-secret
            key: MYSQL_PASSWORD
```

secret.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: rails-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: ENCODED_PASSWORD
```

Comment: In what file are you setting `RAILS_ENV` to 'staging'?

Comment: @Brian I'm using kubernetes secret as environment variable, but I don't understand the detail about how kubernetes implement.

Comment: What does `RAILS_ENV` have to do with "kubernetes secret"?

Comment: @Brian `RAILS_ENV` is one of environment variables set by kubernetes secret, there's other value like `MYSQL_PASSWD`, you can think `secret` like a key/value pair data storage.  The lifecycle might like 1. kubernetes start a pod(container) 2. Load secret as environment variables(I'm not fully understand) 3. Execute command assign at Dockerfile `CMD` (here run a cron proccess).

Comment: Can you show us where/how this cron is being executed? Are you using a k8s job or cronjob? Please add the yaml spec file that you're using.

Comment: Hi @iamnat I've updated deployment.yaml and secret.yaml in question. I'm using the system cron (command `cron -f`), and write crontab by rails gem called `whenever` .

Comment: Ok. So actually everything might be working. How are you checking the output of the ``/tmp/cron_test.log`` file?

Comment: @iamnat `cat /tmp/cron_test.log` and the resule is `rails_env=` (the trailing $RAILS_ENV seem not being seted).

Comment: Where are you running this command? Are you doing a kubectl exec inside the running container?

Comment: @iamnat Yes, I do`kubectl exec -it rails_pod bash` and running the command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131081/discussion-between-iamnat-and-gaga5lala).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of running cron scripts inside the container, you should probably use [CronJobs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/cron-jobs/), where you can set env vars from secrets in the same way you do for deployments.

Comment: I've seen the `CronJob` document but didn't do more survey. I have two questions, 1. Is it possible read env vars set by k8s secret by system cron inside the container? 2. Does there any advantage using CronJob instead of system cron? and CronJob currently is in alpha, does it means it not stable yet? Thanks

Comment: You can go ahead and use CronJob without worrying too much. Amanpreet is right, you should definitely use CronJob, or ScheduledJob or atleast a Job. Are you using a deployment right now?

Comment: @iamnat Hmm... I have to persuade our devops leader to upgrade k8s cluster and use alpha function first. Yes I'm using deployment now.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution after discussion with some guys.

The problem should be docker level not kubernetes level.
https://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2016/02/29/docker-crontab-environment-variables/

Cron process doesn't run as normal login-shell, so it didn't act as our expectation for read environment variables set by docker/k8s.

To solve the problem, we have to make cron process read environment variables  first.

STEP1.

Add one line to dump environment variables at run_cron.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# dump environment variables
printenv | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/export \1/g' >> /etc/profile.d/rails_env.sh

cron -f
```

STEP2.

Make cron read environment variables before executing command.

```
* * * * * . /etc/profile.d/rails_env.sh; ruby my_job.rb >> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1
```

or using bash **--login** option, which would every file under /etc/profile.d

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'ruby my_job.rb >> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1'
```

Then cron work as expectation!

Comment: I used a similar approach but used `export >> /etc/profile.d/rails_env.sh` instead of `printenv` with the `sed` command. I then `source` the file and run the script within my crontab.